# how to populate data in a stringgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, tstringgrid

i dont know how to deal with stringrids, i want to fill it with data, I've succeeded to do it with a listview 
 this is my code to fill the listview..

```
var
 LJSONArray : TJSONArray;
 LItem: TListViewItem;
  I: Integer;
 begin
 LJSONArray := TJSONArray.Create;
 try
 BackendStorage1.Storage.QueryObjects('ShoppingList', [], LJSONArray);
ListView1.ClearItems;
for I := 0 to LJSONArray.Count-1 do
begin
  LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
  LItem.Text := (LJSonArray.Items[I].GetValue<string>('item'));
end;
finally
LJSONArray.Free;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

To add items to a `TStringGrid`, you have to set its [`RowCount`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Grid.TCustomGrid.RowCount) property first and then use its [`Cells`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Grid.TStringGrid.Cells) property to fill them in, eg:

```
var
  LJSONArray : TJSONArray;
  I: Integer;
begin
  LJSONArray := TJSONArray.Create;
  try
    BackendStorage1.Storage.QueryObjects('ShoppingList', [], LJSONArray);
    StringGrid1.RowCount := LJSONArray.Count;
    for I := 0 to LJSONArray.Count-1 do
    begin
      StringGrid1.Cells[0, I] := LJSonArray.Items[I].GetValue<string>('item');
    end;
  finally
    LJSONArray.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Make sure you have set the grid's [`ColumnCount`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Grid.TCustomGrid.ColumnCount) property to at least 1 beforehand, such as at design-time.

Comment: error FixedRows undeclared identifier !! @Remy Lebeau

Comment: @markkk: VCL's `TStringGrid` has a published `FixedRows` property.  Are you using FireMonkey instead of VCL?  FireMonkey's `TStringGrid` does not have a `FixedRows` property, but it does have `RowCount` and `Cells` properties, so just remove the `FixedRows` references if you are indeed using FireMonkey.  And please, next time, be more clear about which framework you are actually using.

Comment: yes, im using firemonkey, and plz edit your answer, many thanks in advance, i'll be more specific nxt time @Remy Lebeau

Comment: @markkk: If you're using FireMonkey, you should edit your question to add that tag, so people know you're not asking about the VCL TStringGrid. We shouldn't have to guess which one you're using.

Comment: @Remy: I see that (now). :-) Still a good point for the OP in the future.

Comment: error again, Coumn index, 0, out of bounds @RemyLebeau

Comment: @markkk: Have you defined any columns in your grid? Have you even looked at the available properties of `TStringGrid`, or read its documentation?

Comment: manged to do it, its works like charm, many thank Mr. @Remy Lebeau